# How to add a javascript variable as action parameter in Laravel form

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I was trying add a js variable as my action parameter where that variable varies for every button a form will be created and will be sent to a bootstrap modal-body(initially modal-body is blank). 
Here is the js code i was trying to assign to modal-body html

```
$('.postComment').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); //this is the id suppose:id='1234abcd'

    var data =  '{{Form::open(array("method" => "POST","route" => ["post.comment",'+id+'],"class" => "form-horizontal"))}}'+
                '{{Form::textarea("comment", null, array("required","class"=>"form-control","placeholder"=>"Add a comment"))}}'+
                '{{Form::submit("Comment",array("class"=>"btn btn-info"))}}'+
                '{{Form::close()}}';
    $('#comment').modal();
    $('#comment').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        $('#comment .modal-body').html(data);
    });
    $("#comment").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
            $('#comment .modal-body').html('');
        });
});
```

When clicking on comment button in the form action appears like this

```
action="/post/comment/+id+"
```

But expected is

```
action="/post/comment/1234abcd"
```

Am I missing something? or doing in wrong way?

Comment: You can't mix php methods and javascript variables. Php runs on server long before page is loaded and javascript runs in browser after page has loaded

Comment: but if I do it using normal html form it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a place holder in the action and replace it using javascript when the click occurs.

The problem with what you are trying to do is the laravel form code runs on server long before the javascript runs in browser

Try

```
 var data =  '{{Form::open(array("method" => "POST","route" => ["post.comment",'+id+'],"class" => "form-horizontal"))}}'+
                '{{Form::textarea("comment", null, array("required","class"=>"form-control","placeholder"=>"Add a comment"))}}'+
                '{{Form::submit("Comment",array("class"=>"btn btn-info"))}}'+
                '{{Form::close()}}';

var $form = $(data);
$form.attr('action', function(_, action){
  return action.replace('+id+', id)
});

$('#comment').modal();
$('#comment').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#comment .modal-body').html($form);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I write the **data** part like this it worked

```
var data =  '<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="post/comment/'+id+'">'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">'+
            '<textarea id="commentBox" name="comment" class="form-control" required></textarea>'+
            '<input type="submit" name="Comment" value="Comment" class="btn btn-info"/>'+
            '</form>';
```

in the form action it showed

```
action="/post/comment/1234abcd"
```

Answer (score -1):

you can write like this

```
   var id123 = $(this).attr('id'); //this is the id suppose:id='1234abcd'

    var data =  '{{Form::open(array("method" => "POST","route" => ["post.comment'+id123+'"],"class" => "form-horizontal"))}}'+
                '{{Form::textarea("comment", null, array("required","class"=>"form-control","placeholder"=>"Add a comment"))}}'+
                '{{Form::submit("Comment",array("class"=>"btn btn-info"))}}'+
                '{{Form::close()}}';
```

Comment: I will give it a try now

Comment: This won't work. The `id` doesn't exist at the time the php is compiled

Comment: Nope it throws an ErrorException as this id was not defined but I defined it earlier.

Comment: did you put id attribute in your button tag?

Comment: I solved it using normal html form instead of blade form